# Extraer un registro y sus relaciones - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Necesito extraer un registro y sus relaciones pasando como parámetro su respectivo id. La cuestión es que me devuelve mas de un registro. Definitivamente algo estoy haciendo mal.

Controlador

```
public function show($id, TicketRepository $repository)
{
  $ticket = $repository->show($id);
  return response()->json(['ticket' => $ticket], 200);
}
```

Repositorio

```
public function show($ticket)
{
    return Ticket::findOrFail($ticket)->show();
}
```

Scope

```
public function scopeShow($query)
{
  return $query
  ->with('messages')
  ->with('contact')
  ->with('origin')
  ->with('status')
  ->with('priority')
  ->with('departament');
}
```

Resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme explicado. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dejo la solución por si a alguien le sirve:

Repositorio

```
public function show($ticket)
{
  return Ticket::show()->findOrFail($ticket);
}
```